# Why is AppEngine Flex CPU so much more expensive than Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

For London region, the current [price per vCPU for AppEngine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-instances) is $0.063/hour. The [price per vCPU for Cloud Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#custommachinetypepricing) is $0.040692/hour. What are the reasons why AppEngine is ~50% more expensive per vCPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an additional service on top of Google Compute, so they are just charging for additional features such as auto scaling. That's assuming we are talking about the same thing?

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/

Comment: We are talking about the same thing.

Comment: @Ztyx if your question answered here?

To make the answer more explicit, consider that you will not run Flex instances all the time instead they will automatically stop when there is no need for them. This requires maintenance and organizational overhead, as Nick mentioned, loadbalancer is one example of such overhead.

Answer (score -1):

Where did you get the values for the cost that you shared? As per the documentation I have found, these are the current values for vCPUs located in London (as an example; you can choose the region you prefer):

- [App Engine Flexible vCPU](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-instances): $0.063 per core per hour.
- [Compute Engine vCPU:](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#custommachinetypepricing) $0.040692 per vCPU per hour.

Lower prices can be obtained in Compute Engine with [sustained usage discounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#sustained_use) or using [preemptible instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible#what_is_a_preemptible_instance), though.

Comment: Really sorry. I have no idea where I got the second price from. Updated the question with correct price and added links to sources.

Comment: You may have been referring to the F1-micro bursting rates. The F1-micro bursting rates are based on 0.2 vCPU that can burst up to full CPU for a short period. The rates on these are closer to your original (pre-edited numbers) at $0.00x rather than $0.0x:  
"Note: f1-micro instances get 0.2 of a vCPU and are allowed to burst up to a full vCPU for short periods. g1-small instances get 0.5 of a vCPU and are allowed to burst up to a full vCPU for short periods."